# out of range error in vb.net and access get maxnumber

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

iam trying to get the max number from table and insert it to another number 
 with vb.net 2008 and access db 2003 this my code

```
Dim strQ As String = "SELECT MAX(IDbatch) from batches "
        Dim IDbatch As Integer
        Dim cmdQ As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strQ, con)
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()

        End If
        Dim QReader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim it As Integer
        QReader = cmdQ.ExecuteReader
        If QReader.FieldCount > 0 Then
            While QReader.Read
                it = QReader.Item("IDbatch")
                MsgBox(it)
            End While
        End If
```

I am getting Out of range error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to

```
Dim strQ As String = "SELECT MAX(IDbatch) as MaxIDbatch from batches "
```

and your code that read the value to

```
it = QReader.Item("MaxIDbatch")
```

As you have it now the `MAX(IDbatch)` creates a field with a different name than `IDbatch` and trying to retrieve the content of that field using the name `IDbatch` fails giving the `Index out of range exception`

By the way, your check for `FieldCount > 0` will be always true also in cases where there is no record in the batches table. So, if you have done that to protect in case of no record, then it is better to write

```
Dim result = cmdQ.ExecuteScalar()
if result IsNot Nothing then
    Dim it = Convert.ToInt32(result)
    MsgBox(it)
End If
```

And with this approach you could also leave out the aliasing on the IDbatch field

Comment: I really hope the OP is not using this to get the next batch number :)

Comment: thanks steve  i try the code and the max number in the databse is 3 and it give me 3 when i try it the the access but it give me 24 in the result .

Comment: i also add new batch  so the max become 4 the result still the same 24 how can to debug and find from where this 24 is come from

Comment: @Fionnuala of course this is not a valid way to work in a multiuser/multithread environment, but I think that this is harmless on a single user/single thread MS-Access database.

Comment: @Samoul this will give back the highest value of the field named IDbatch not the number of rows in your datatable. If you have three rows but the highest value is 24 you get 24 not 3 (or 4).

Comment: @fionnuala yes its for one user because of that iam using access .@steve the highest number in the IDbatch is 4 not 24 but i still getting 24 even when i add more items in the batch table

Comment: when i use the SQL in access iam getting what i want .SELECT MAX(IDbatch) as MaxIDbatch from batches . but when i use it in vb.net iam getting strange value as i said 24

Comment: Strange, are you sure that you are looking at the same database? Check your connectionstring? Are you using the `|DATADIRECTORY| ` substitution string?

Comment: @steve  after your comment i remember that i am using another database for testing and the real one in debug folder . so the code is working